# Differenc between escaping slash with one/two backslash in preg_match() in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

In regular expression sometimes I encountered the forward slash, I have tried to escape it using one backslash and two backslashes and realize the return is the same. So I would like to understand it more clearly.

Example code:

```
var_dump(preg_match("/^\\/$/D", "/"));

var_dump(preg_match("/^\/$/D", "/"));
```

They both give the same output

```
int(1)
```

In my understanding escaping it with two backslashes seem correct because when PHP parse the string the first backslash(\) escape the second backslash(\) , and when parsing the regular expression the backslash(\) then escape the forward slash(/).

Is there any difference between them? Thank you.

Comment: There is a difference. In the first one with two backslashes you escape the backslash, making it literal. In the second you escape the forward slash, making it literal.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I once think the backslash becomes the literal, but if it is the case then the first example `var_dump(preg_match("/^\\/$/D", "/"));` should not match because I only provides `"/"` as the subject. But if the backslash becomes a literal then it should match `"\/"` instead. Please correct me if I misunderstand something. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's exactly the same.

In a quoted or an heredoc string you can figure a literal backslash with one or two backslashes. This particularity is due to the fact that the backslash is used as escape character for these kind of strings. You can display the strings to have confirmation of this fact.

In fine, the regex engine receives only one backslash that escapes the delimiter `/` in the two cases.

Note: to figure a literal backslash for a pattern written in quoted string you need 3 or 4 backslashes (because the backslash is the escape character for the pattern too and must be escaped a second time):

```
var_dump(preg_match('~^a\\\o$~', 'a\o'));
var_dump(preg_match('~^a\\\\o$~', 'a\o'));
var_dump(preg_match('~^a\\\o$~', 'a\\o'));
var_dump(preg_match('~^a\\\\o$~', 'a\\o'));
```

---

As any other character, to figure a backslash in quoted string you only need to write it once, but since this character is used to escape, you need sometime to write two backslashes for disambiguation, in particular when an escape sequence follows. Examples:

```
echo "a\b"; # a\b
echo 'a\b'; # a\b
echo "a\\b"; # a\b
echo 'a\\b'; # a\b

echo "a\tb";   # a    b
echo "a\\tb";  # a\tb
echo "a\\\tb"; # a\    b

echo 'a\'b';   # a'b
echo 'a\\'b';  # parse error
echo 'a\\\'b'; # a\'b
```

Note: The only wysiwyg kind of string is the nowdoc string:

```
echo <<<'EOD'
\\
EOD;

# \\
```