# PHP - Escaping double backslash inside a string

Tags: php, escaping

Which is the correct way for escaping a double backslash in a PHP string? The following code output is identical:

```
echo "foo\\\bar";
echo "foo\\\\bar";
```

Output:

```
foo\\bar
foo\\bar
```

Comment: "More correct" would be the second version, IMHO. The first one also works here in this particular instance, because `\b` is _not_ a recognized escape sequence. But now imagine, you at some point had to change the word `bar` to `tar` ...

Comment: Relevant: [why 3 backslash equal 4 backslash in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28062568/2943403) and [How to properly escape a backslash to match a literal backslash in single-quoted and double-quoted PHP regex patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20818283/2943403) and [Differenc between escaping slash with one/two backslash in preg_match() in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39340442/2943403) and [PHP and backslashes in strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9908002/2943403)

Comment: [Right way to escape backslash in PHP regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11044136/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `\b` has no function, so will be displayed as such: `\b`.
- `\\` is an
  escaped backslash and is displayed as `\`.

So two backslashes won't do because it will only display one. Three will be sufficient and four just means two escaped backslashes.

So they're both correct, however, four backslashes is "safer", especially when what follows can vary. Also, you don't want to rely on `\b` having no function forever.